# Cannot compose correct Linq query for a class having collection properties - getting EfCore5 translation errors

Tags: linq, iqueryable, ef-core-5.0

I have flat collection of the following data (`IQueryable<Article>`) which was obtained by querying DB:

| ArticleId | LanguageName | ArticleText | ExtraData1 | ExtraData2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | English | EngText1 | Something1 | Something2 |
| 1 | English | EngText2 | Another1 | Another2 |
| 1 | French | FraText1 | Blabla1 |  |
| 2 | English | EngText2 | Ololo1 | Blabla2 |
| 2 | German | GerText1 |  | Naturlisch2 |

Now I need to fill the `IQueryable<AgregatedArticle>`: the idea is grouping by `ArticleId` and putting repeating data into nested list:

```cs
public class AgregatedArticle {
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public List<Data> ArticleTexts { get; set; }

    public class Data {
        public string LanguageName { get; set; }
        public string ArticleText { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot make it: I am getting various **EfCore5** translation errors and don't know: if it's me or EfCore5 bugs or limitations. I wasted 3 days trying different approaches. Please help - I was unable to find suitable examples in Internet. The problem comes up when I try to fill `ArticleTexts` property.

Here is the simplified example:

```cs
private async Task<IQueryable<LawArticleAggregated>> GetLawArticlesGroupedById(DbSet<LawArticleDetail> dbSet, string userContentLangRestriction = null)
{
    var dbContext = await GetDbContextAsync();

    var articlesQuery =
        (from articleIds in dbSet.Select(x => x.ArticleId).Distinct()
        from articlesPerId in dbSet
            .Where(x => x.ArticleId == articleIds.ArticleId)
        join askedL in dbContext.Langs
            .Where(l => l.LanguageCode == userContentLangRestriction)
            on
                articlesPerId.LanguageCode
                equals
                askedL.StringValue
            into askedLanguages
        from askedLawLanguage in askedLanguages.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join fallbackL in dbContext.Langs
            .Where(l => l.LanguageCode == CoreConstants.LanguageCodes.English)
        on
            articlesPerId.LanguageCode
            equals
            fallbackL.StringValue
        into fallbackLanguages
        from fallbackLanguage in fallbackLanguages.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new
        {
            ArticleId = articleIds.ArticleId,
            ArticleText = articlesPerId.ArticleText,
            LanguageName = askedLawLanguage.ShortName ?? fallbackLanguage.ShortName
        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.ArticleId).ThenBy(x => x.LanguageName).ThenBy(x => x.ArticleText);

    await articlesQuery.LoadAsync();

    var aggregatedArticleData = articlesQuery.Select(x => new
    {
        ArticleId = x.ArticleId,
        ArticleText = x.ArticleText,
        LanguageName = x.LanguageName
    });

    var aggregatedArticles = articlesQuery.Select(x => x.ArticleId).Distinct().Select(x => new ArticleAggregated
    {
        ArticleId = x.ArticleId,
        ArticleTexts = aggregatedArticleData.Where(a => a.ArticleId == x.ArticleId)
            .Select(x => new LawArticleAggregated.Data
            {
                ArticleText = x.ArticleText,
                LanguageName = x.LanguageName
            }).ToList()
    });

    return aggregatedArticles;
}
```

For this specific code the exception is as follows:

> Unable to translate collection subquery in projection since the parent
> query doesn't project key columns of all of it's tables which are
> required to generate results on client side. This can happen when
> trying to correlate on keyless entity or when using 'Distinct' or
> 'GroupBy' operations without projecting all of the key columns.

Comment: Post your code. An `IQueryable<T>` represents a query. It doesn't contain anything so it can't be "filled". That query is translated to SQL by EF Core. If something can't be translated to SQL an exception will be thrown. What you want to do is *not* a `GROUP BY` though

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos Thank you - I've added the code. Yes, I know how it works under the hood - sorry for not being precise. I mean that **EfCore** cannot translate my query throwing various translation exceptions, for this reason I cannot fill my code collections with DB data when `ToList` is used later on.

Comment: You already loaded everything into memory with `LoadAsync()` then discarded the result. Use `ToListAsync()` instead and actually use the loaded data. If you try to use `articlesQuery` again you'll execute a *new* query. You're loading the same data over and over again

Comment: First off, do not create flat query result set, because then it cannot be grouped to produce what you want due to EF Core [GroupBy limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#groupby). The only way to produce such query shape is to **not** base it on flat result.  It's hard to give you good advice because all these joins are hard to follow - don't you have normal relationships / navigation properties ?

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos When I materialized the whole flat result - it did work. Of course, I needed to to change return result from `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable`. I will need to make other changes if I stick to this approach, because meanwhile after shaping an entity list data, traditional filter and paging are applied in our code which are translated to SQL code. So I will need to move this part into current method, too to get only needed page chunk... Probably there is different approach to retain IQueryable... would be nice.

Comment: @ivan-stoev I've tried to, but this one is what I came up finally to at least make it work somehow... Unfortunately, those entities are not bound in model builder, since they are aggregated representation of already existing extended class bound to real DB table (and no, we are not allowed to create VIEWS :) ): `LawArticleDetail`... But FYI, I tried to use `Include` before in other places and bumped into many issues in **EfCore5** (usually it happens when there are more than 1 Include), so I ended up with creating all joins manually.

Comment: @IvanStoev could you please show how to create `IQueryable<AgregatedArticle>` (and not to end up with flat data set as I ended up with) given we have `DbSet<LawArticleDetail> dbSet`, the list of test data is in the table of my question? I've tried to use `GroupBy` as well - of course, this does not work. So I have no clue... Please ignore other tables for now, I have shown them to demonstrate full SELECT (just in case if it is wrong in some unexpected place).

Comment: I didn't say to use `Include`. Navigation properties are much more than that - in queries they represent joins with proper cardinality and help a lot for building proper queries (which cannot be said for SQL). Anyway, the only way to produce list in the final result is to use correlated subquery.

Comment: @IvanStoev I've tried to (using `GroupJoin`-`SelectMany`), but keep getting **EfCore** translation errors. Neither I can find example similar to my case in Internet... Main issue: I cannot find the way to assign my collection property `ArticleTexts` using projection without getting translation exception

Answer (score 0):

I think I have reverse engineered your query. Big difference that we cannot return `IQueryable` from this funcrtio, but prepared `IEnumerable`. So if you have pagination later, better to pass page info into function parameters.

```cs
private async Task<IEnumerable<LawArticleAggregated>> GetLawArticlesGroupedById(DbSet<LawArticleDetail> dbSet, string userContentLangRestriction = null)
{
    var dbContext = await GetDbContextAsync();

    var articlesQuery =
        from article in dbSet
        from askedLawLanguage in dbContext.Langs
            .Where(askedLawLanguage => askedLawLanguage.LanguageCode == userContentLangRestriction && article.LanguageCode == askedLawLanguage.StringValue)
            .DefaultIfEmpty()
        from fallbackLanguage in dbContext.Langs
            .Where(fallbackLanguage => fallbackLanguage.LanguageCode == CoreConstants.LanguageCodes.English && article.LanguageCode == fallbackLanguage.StringValue)
            .DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new
        {
            ArticleId = article.ArticleId,
            ArticleText = article.ArticleText,
            LanguageName = askedLawLanguage.ShortName ?? fallbackLanguage.ShortName
        };

    articlesQuery = articlesQuery
        .OrderBy(x => x.ArticleId)
        .ThenBy(x => x.LanguageName)
        .ThenBy(x => x.ArticleText);

    var loaded = await articlesQuery.ToListAsync();

    // group on the client side
    var aggregatedArticles = loaded.GroupBy(x => x.ArticleId)
        .Select(g => new ArticleAggregated
        {
            ArticleId = g.Key,
            ArticleTexts = g.Select(x => new LawArticleAggregated.Data
            {
                ArticleText = x.ArticleText,
                LanguageName = x.LanguageName
            }).ToList()
        });

    return aggregatedArticles;
}
```

Comment: I think the grouping needs to take place on server, because paging needs to be applied after it to retain correct UI grid paging: 1 `ArticleAggregated` entry ~ 1 grid row in UI

Comment: Such grouping on server is possible only with EF Core 6. But we can emulate such behaviour, if you pass pagination info as parameter of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following implementation (I show it "as is", without simplification from the first message to demonstrate the approach, slightly modified from the initial variant to use proper paging):

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<LawArticleAggregated>> GetLawArticlesGroupedByIdListAsync(
    DbSet<LawArticleDetail> dbSet,
    Expression<Func<IQueryable<LawArticleDetail>, IQueryable<LawArticleDetail>>> filterFunc,
    int skipCount,
    int maxResultCount,
    string userContentLangRestriction = null,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default
)
{
    var dbContext = await GetDbContextAsync();

    var articlesQuery =
        (from articleIds in filterFunc.Compile().Invoke(dbSet).Select(x => new { x.TenantId, x.LawArticleId })
            .Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.TenantId).OrderByDescending(x => x.LawArticleId).Skip(skipCount).Take(maxResultCount)
         from articlesPerId in dbSet
            .Where(x => x.TenantId == articleIds.TenantId && x.LawArticleId == articleIds.LawArticleId)
         join askedL in dbContext.FixCodeValues
            .Where(l =>
                 l.DomainId == CoreConstants.Domains.CENTRAL_TOOLS
                 && l.CodeName == CoreConstants.FieldTypes.LANGUAGE
                 && l.LanguageCode == userContentLangRestriction)
             on
                 articlesPerId.LanguageCode
                 equals
                 askedL.StringValue
             into askedLanguages
         from askedLawLanguage in askedLanguages.DefaultIfEmpty()
         join fallbackL in dbContext.FixCodeValues
            .Where(l =>
                 l.DomainId == CoreConstants.Domains.CENTRAL_TOOLS
                 && l.CodeName == CoreConstants.FieldTypes.LANGUAGE
                 && l.LanguageCode == CoreConstants.LanguageCodes.English)
         on
            articlesPerId.LanguageCode
            equals
            fallbackL.StringValue
         into fallbackLanguages
         from fallbackLanguage in fallbackLanguages.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new
         {
             TenantId = articleIds.TenantId,
             LawArticleId = articleIds.LawArticleId,
             Shortcut = articlesPerId.Shortcut,
             ArticleText = articlesPerId.ArticleText,
             LanguageName = askedLawLanguage.ShortName ?? fallbackLanguage.ShortName
         })
        .OrderBy(x => x.TenantId).ThenByDescending(x => x.LawArticleId).ThenBy(x => x.Shortcut).ThenBy(x => x.LanguageName).ThenBy(x => x.ArticleText);

    var articleList = await articlesQuery.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

    var aggregatedArticles = articleList.GroupBy(x => new { x.TenantId, x.LawArticleId })
        .Select(g => new LawArticleAggregated
        {
            TenantId = g.Key.TenantId,
            LawArticleId = g.Key.LawArticleId,
            ArticleTexts = g.Select(x => new LawArticleAggregated.Data
            {
                Shortcut = x.Shortcut,
                ArticleText = x.ArticleText,
                LanguageName = x.LanguageName
            }).ToList()
        });

    return aggregatedArticles;
}

private async Task<long> GetLawArticlesGroupedByIdCountAsync(
    DbSet<LawArticleDetail> dbSet,
    Expression<Func<IQueryable<LawArticleDetail>, IQueryable<LawArticleDetail>>> filterFunc,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default
)
{
    return await filterFunc.Compile().Invoke(dbSet).GroupBy(x => new { x.TenantId, x.LawArticleId }).LongCountAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```